# Mysql using filesort even when using index and only one row

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, app and pricehistory
there is a primary index id on app which is an int
on pricehistory i have two fields id_app (int), price(float) and dateup (date) and an unique index on "id_app, dateup"

i'm trying to get the latest (of date) price of an app :

```
select app.id,
       (  select price 
          from pricehistory 
          where id_app=app.id 
          order by dateup desc limit 1) 
from app 
where id=147
```

the explain select is kind of weird because it return 1 row but it still makes a filesort :

```
id  select_type        table        type   possible_keys            key      key_len   ref     rows  Extra      
1   PRIMARY            app          const  PRIMARY                  PRIMARY     4      const      1   
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY pricehistory ref    id_app,id_app_2,id_app_3 id_app      4      const      1  Using where; Using filesort
```

why does it need to filesort when there is only 1 row ? and why it's file sorting when i'm indexing all it need (id_app and dateup)

app has 1 million rows and i'm using innodb

edit: a sql fiddle explaining the problem:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/085027/1

edit3 :
a new fiddle with another request with the same problem :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7682/6

edit4: this fiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2785c/2 ) shows that the query proposed doesn't work because it select all the data from pricehistory just to fetch the ones i want

Comment: What is your MySql version ? I've tried this query on version 5.7, it hasn't used the filesort when a composite index on "id_app, dateup" has been created.

Comment: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1-log (Debian)

Comment: I've added a sql fiddle with 2 index, and mysql is using the longest index instead of the shortest, but i don't know why

Comment: The query in the sqlfiddle selects only `price_fr` column, and MySql prefers the longest index because this index contains values of `price_fr`, while the other index does not contain this column. MySql reads results of query directly from that index, and doesn't read the table at all.

Comment: if i change the index to :
   UNIQUE KEY `id_app` (`id_app`,`price_fr`,`dateup`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id_app_3` (`id_app`,`dateup`,`price_fr`)
it still use the index id_app and do a filesort, but if i remove the index id_app, it will use the index id_app_3 and don't make a filesort

Comment: I haven't 5.5 and cannot test it, but try add `order by id_app desc, dateup desc limit 1` in the subquery.

Comment: you can modify the request on the sqlfiddle link to test on 5.5. I did it and that didn't changed anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick rule of thumb for which order columns should go in an index:

1. Columns referenced in the WHERE clause with an equality condition (`=`).
2. Choose *one* of:

   a. Columns referenced in the ORDER BY clause.

   b. Columns referenced in a GROUP BY clause.

   c. Columns referenced in the WHERE clause with a range condition (`!=`, `>`, `<`, `IN`, `BETWEEN`, `IS [NOT] NULL`).
3. Columns referenced in the SELECT-list.

See [How to Design Indexes, Really.](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)

In this case, I was able to remove the filesort with this index:

```
mysql> alter table pricehistory add  key bk1 (id_app, dateup, price_fr);
```

And here's the EXPLAIN, showing no filesort, and the improvement of "Using index":

```
mysql> explain select price_fr from pricehistory where id_app=1 order by dateup desc\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pricehistory
         type: ref
possible_keys: bk1
          key: bk1
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

You can make this index UNIQUE if you want to.

I had to drop the other unique keys, to avoid confusing the optimizer.

Comment: when I use the query as a subquery, it still do a filesort, but not if I do the request directly

Comment: @user3416510, thanks for the report. Yes, there are some cases where subqueries are optimized poorly, and indexes don't help. It's good that you tested both forms of your query and compared the performance and optimization. That's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The two `UNIQUE KEY`s are causing the problem. I changed your fiddle to the following, and it works without a filesort:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pricehistory` (
  `id_app` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateup` date NOT NULL,
  `price_fr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_app` (`id_app`,`dateup`,`price_fr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=345 ;


INSERT INTO pricehistory
(id_app, price_fr,dateup)
VALUES
('1', '4.99', now()),
('2', '0.45', now());
```

The `EXPLAIN` gives:

```
ID    SELECT_TYPE    TABLE           TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS    KEY         KEY_LEN    REF    ROWS    EXTRA
1     SIMPLE         pricehistory    ref     id_app           id_app      4          const  1       Using where; Using index
```

There's no reason to use a `UNIQUE KEY` on both `(id_app,dateup)` and `(id_app,price_fr,dateup)`, as they are redundant. I'm pretty confident that redundancy is making MySQL somehow uncertain of itself so that it errs on the side of doing a filesort.

Comment: unique keyword is  not like PRIMARY, you can have multiple unique index. I tried to modify the second index instead of removing to :

Comment: I'm aware of that. The point is that the `UNIQUE KEY`s in your original code were redundant -- one of them included all of the columns used in the other. In any event, at least in the fiddle, restructuring as above to remove the redundancy stops MySQL from using filesort. Also, FYI, your code didn't come through in your comment.

Comment: unique keyword is  not like PRIMARY, you can have multiple unique index. I tried to modify the second index instead of removing to :
 UNIQUE KEY `id_app` (`id_app`,`price_fr`,`dateup`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_app_3` (`id_app`,`dateup`)
and eventough they are not the same, it still use filesort. But I'll remove the "unique" to one of the index, thank you

Comment: The issue is that `UNIQUE KEY id_app (id_app,price_fr,dateup)` uses all of the fields in `UNIQUE KEY id_app (id_app,dateup)`. So, it's redundant. Let me know if this doesn't fix it.

Comment: i've added a new fiddle

Comment: It has exactly the same issue -- you have completely redundant `UNIQUE KEY`s. If you drop the one on `(id_app,price_fr,dateup)`, it works just fine. `UNIQUE KEY`s aren't like other keys, and the overlap here is throwing off the optimizer. `UNIQUE KEY foo (a,b,c)` is completely redundant of `UNIQUE KEY bar (a,c,b)`, so having both can cause the optimizer to get confused.

Comment: damn there is a problem on the sqlfiddle, my modifications are gone :/
this is the right url : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7682/6

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the unique to one of the indexes. It seems like if it's not useful it's better to not put the unique keyword.
thanks to both of you

edit:
damn, with a different query with 2 tables, the filesort is back :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7682/6

Comment: I would be tempted to change that example to `explain 
select app.id, MAX(pricehistory.dateup)
from app 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pricehistory
ON pricehistory.id_app = app.id 
and price_fr != -1 
where app.id > 0;` which eliminates the dependent sub query and also the filesort.

Comment: i can't do that because the "order by dateup desc limit 1" is gone in your query. I Need the latest pricehistory and only one (there can be multiple price with the same id_app)

Comment: It can still be done removing the dependent sub query, but if it isn't just the latest dateup that you want then you will need to let us know which columns you require (you can do a join against a non dependent sub query to get the max dateup for each example, then join that against pricehistory again to get the rest of the row for that id_app and dateup)

Comment: i need dateup and price_fr

Comment: Then something like this `select app.id, pricehistory.dateup, pricehistory.price_fr 
from app  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( 
  SELECT id_app, MAX(dateup) AS max_dateup
  FROM pricehistory
  WHERE price_fr != -1  
  GROUP BY id_app
) Sub1
ON Sub1.id_app = app.id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN pricehistory 
ON pricehistory.id_app = app.id  
AND pricehistory.dateup = Sub1.max_dateup
and pricehistory.price_fr != -1  
where app.id > 0;`

Comment: with your code, what if we have 2 price history with the same id_app ? it will give 2 lines instead of 1 ? edit: it is badly optimised because for each app, it will list every pricehistory, group them by id_app and extract some infos

Comment: No. If they have multiple price history its gets the latest one (the possible problem is if there are multiple latest pricehistory records for an app_id which both have exactly the same dateup). The query joins app against a sub query against pricehistory that gets the latest dateup for each id_app, and then joins that against pricehistory matching on both app_id AND that the dateup matches the latest dateup for that app_id. This should be far more efficient than a correlated sub query (which is executed separately for each returned row).

Comment: are you sure it's more efficient ? To me it looks like for each row it will group by to whole table, which is far slower than just reading the index with the subquery

Comment: No, it is doing a join. It will perform the sub query once (nothing in the sub query refers to any fields outside the sub query), and does a GROUP BY to get the max dateup for each and every id_app. The results of this sub query are then joined against the app table, and pricehistory, checking the dateup as well so only the latest row for each id_app is joined.

Comment: Well, i've tested with 1 million rows in pricehistory, but it's not at all performant because the derived table has 1 million rows, even if only a portion of them are useful. See this sqlfiddle which show 2 and 3 rows while i need only one : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2785c/2

Comment: In this situation you can add the check for the value of id_app in a WHERE clause in the sub query as well.

Comment: the sub query don't have access to this data :(

Comment: You just add the WHERE clause into the sub query as well. It is a fixed value as you are only looking for one value or id_app. Ie, in your SQL fiddle you have a WHERE clause for where app.id =2. As you join to the sub query based on `ON pricehistory.id_app = app.id` you know that in the sub query id_app must also be 2. If you are doing it for all values of app.id then you need all the values from the subquery anyway.

Comment: in fact my query is more complicated than app.id=2, i don't have only one row and the "where" use some other fields of "app"

Comment: If the amount of rows from the sub query is massively in excess of what is required then you can change the sub query to do a join to the app table and doing your checks there as well. However if the numbers are not that great then the cost of doing this will not be worth the minor saving from reducing the number of excess rows on the JOIN.